# symbol not found errors with glibc

Tags: node.js, docker, oracle11g, glibc, node-oracledb

Recently, I started working with Docker to run my Node project and wanted to add the Oracle instant client driver. As far as I know Oracle instant client driver is compiled against `glibc` library while my Docker images which is `Alpine` based includes `musl` library.

So I needed a way to include the `glibc` libraries and I stumbled upon [docker-glibc-builder](https://github.com/sgerrand/docker-glibc-builder) which packages the `glibc` libraries as a compressed package.

After including the `glibc` library into the container I started noticing the following errors when ever my Node project would call the Oracle the instant driver.

```
Error: Error relocating /opt/oracle/drivers/instantclient/libclntsh.so.11.1: getcontext: symbol not found
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:568:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:32:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/oracledb/index.js:1:80)
```

Anyone run into such an error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I needed a way to include the glibc libraries

Note that you can *not* mix and match two separate `libc` libraries in a single process. You *must* choose one or the other. Further, you *must* build against the same library you are going to use at runtime (merely including runtime packages in your Docker image is not sufficient).

[According to musl wiki](http://wiki.musl-libc.org/wiki/Open_Issues), musl does not provide `getcontext`. The error you get is consistent with you continuing to use musl, and not glibc.

Comment: Well does Alpine allow the replacement of `musl` with `libc` ?

Comment: @nixgadgets If Alpine does allow replacement, it would require a complete rebuild of every binary, so I seriously doubt that it does. Note that you don't *actually* need to replace anything. You *do* however need to have Node built against `glibc`.

Comment: Thats something i did try. Building Node against glibc. But i have a feeling i didnt do it properly. All i did was to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH. May be i shouldve gotten glibc python as well

Comment: Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not at al the same as building (compiling and linking) against GLIBC headers and libraries.

Comment: Can you please give me some tips or links to look at ?

Comment: @nixgadgets If you don't know where to begin, you will likely be better off selecting a GLIBC-based distribution. If you want to continue using Alpine, you'll need to build Linux-musl-to-Linux-glibc crosstool. Start here: http://crosstool-ng.org/